# Deployment Failed Developer Edition

Tags: apex, deployment, class

I can't save a class in a developer org. I receive this error: "Can't alter metadata in an active org".
How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: That error message is surfaced when you attempt to modify Apex in a production org. Are you sure this is a Developer Edition?

Comment: Yes, it is a developer environment

Comment: If you view the Company Information screen in the org, what edition does it say you are in?

Comment: Organization Edition: Developer Edition

Comment: How are you modifying the class, developer console, IDE, etc.?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new class or attempting to save a different class?

Comment: If I edit the class using IDE or Salesforce console I get the error, while if I change the class editing it from setup / apex class it works